# Remove An Unique Item From Shopping-Cart In Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete an item from the `cart` and I have some issues to do it. Here is the function:

```
def cart_contents(request):
    """
    Ensures that the cart contents are available when rendering
    every page
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart_items = []
    total = 0
    destination_count = 0
    for id, quantity in cart.items():
        destination = get_object_or_404(Destinations, pk=id)
        #remove = request.session.pop('cart', {id}) <<<<<<
        price = destination.price
        total += quantity * destination.price
        destination_count += quantity
        cart_items.append({'id': id, 'quantity': quantity, 'destination': destination, 'price':price, 'remove':remove})
    #cart_item will loop into the cart.
    return {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'destination_count': destination_count}
```

Template.html

```
{% for item in cart_items %}

{{ item.remove }}

{% endfor %}
```

I've added a remove variable `remove = request.session.pop('cart', {id})` but if I use it in the code it will first not allow me to add more than one item and when I click the trash-can-button to remove the item it deletes all the `cart` in the session.
The following image has two items in the card based by its id and the quantity as `{'id', quantity} = {'2': 1, '3': 2}`.

[image: shopping cart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I made `cart` and `quantity` correlate each other. So, if you have three items in the cart you can delete/decrement until it reach 0 in the cart and if so, the cart will redirect to the destinations url.

```
def adjust_cart(request, id):
    """
    Adjust the quantity of the specified product to the specified
    amount

    url for this function should be <str:id> not <int:id>
    - otherwise you need to add str() method for each dict representation.
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    quantity = cart[id] - 1 #decreases the cart quantity until deletes from cart

    if quantity > 0:
        cart[id] = quantity
    else:
        cart.pop(id)
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    if not cart: #if all products be deleted from cart return to destination page
        return redirect(reverse('destination'))
    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

cart.html

```
{% for item in cart_items %}
</tr>
...
  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><a href="{% url 'adjust_cart' item.id%}" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    path('adjust/<str:id>/', views.adjust_cart, name="adjust_cart"),
]
```

Remembering that `cart_items` is a list with appended dictionary. Please if any acronym is wrong you can correct me.

Answer (score 2):

`request.session.pop('cart')` will remove the cart in the session. Assuming that when you click the delete icon, you pass the id of the cart item, you can get the cart from the session and delete the necessary id and set the session again with the new cart value:

```
cart = request.session.get("cart", {})
id_to_be_removed = request.POST["id_to_be_removed"]

# do other things here or anywhere else

if id_to_be_removed in cart:
   del cart[id_to_be_removed]  # remove the id
   request.session["cart"] = cart

# return
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to add this approach within or outside of the for loop?

Comment: @EliasPrado no, you just have to call it whenever you have the id you want to remove, but if you have multiple ids that needs to be removed, you can place the `del cart[id]` inside a loop